# failure in displaying from VBO

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, vbo

i'm using vbos to display cubes. This is my code :

//creating VBO's

```
                vertices = cb.getVertices();
                colors = cb.getColors();
                outlinesColors = cb.getOutlinesColors();
                indices = cb.getIndices();

                // vertex buffer
                gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb.gpuBufferVertices);
                gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(vertices), vertices,
                        GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

                // color and outlines color buffer
                gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb.gpuBufferColors);
                gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colors.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(colors) + outlinesColors.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(outlinesColors), null,
                        GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                gl.glBufferSubData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0, colors.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(colors),
                        colors);

                gl.glBufferSubData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,colors.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(colors), outlinesColors.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(outlinesColors),
                        outlinesColors);

                // indices buffer
                gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb.gpuBufferIndices);
                gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(indices), indices,
                        GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

NB: cb is a buffer from the list of buffers wich contains the data of the cubes

and this is the code for rendering :

```
for (CellQuadBuffer cb : listBuffers) {
        vertices = cb.getVertices();
        colors = cb.getColors();
        outlinesColors = cb.getOutlinesColors();
        indices = cb.getIndices();

        if (vboEnabled) {
            //rendering the cubes
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb.gpuBufferVertices);
            gl.glVertexPointer(CellQuadBuffer.NB_COORDINATES_PER_VERTEX, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

            gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb.gpuBufferColors);
            gl.glColorPointer(CellQuadBuffer.NB_COLORS_PER_VERTEX, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0 ,0);


            gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb.gpuBufferIndices);

            gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_QUADS, cb.getNbIndices(), GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

            // rendering the outlinesColors of the cubes
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb.gpuBufferColors);
            gl.glColorPointer(CellQuadBuffer.NB_COLORS_PER_VERTEX, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0,colors.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(colors));

            gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_LINES,  cb.getNbIndices(), GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);



        }
```

Now when i run there is problems in the display :some cubes not displayed at all and problemes in displaying the outlines colors and i think because i'm using the same vbo for colors and outlinesColors and probably there is a mistake when specifying the offset to glBufferSubData or glColorPointer but i couldn't figure it out .

Comment: Does it work without rendering the outlines? How many components do your colors have? What's the value of NB_COLORS_PER_VERTEX? What do the colors in your arrays/lists look like (i.e. the `Color` class)?

Comment: Hmm, your code looks fine to me so maybe there's a problem with the data. Since you're redrawing the same cubes with different colors but without adding some scaleing/offset you might suffer from z-fighting or your outlines being discarded by the z-buffer. Some images on what you'd expect and what you get instead would help to better understand your problem.

Comment: NB_COLORS_PER_VERTEX = 4
and colors have 4 components and they are stored in a ByteBuffer .

Comment: ok thank you for your help i'll try to upload some images but the thing is when i change in this line :
   gl.glColorPointer(CellQuadBuffer.NB_COLORS_PER_VERTEX, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0,colors.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(colors));

and i put something like 5121 in the last parameter i start getting some outlines rendered correctly and the whole cubes rendered i thing there is a problem of adress here but i believe colors.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(colors) is the right adress because that's where storing the outlines began in the vbo .

Comment: Did you check the offset during vbo creation and rendering? Is it still the same?

Comment: it's true there is a problem in the offset , it changed between the creation and rendering so i added this variable when the creation :
x=colors.capacity() * Buffers.sizeOfBufferElem(colors);
and used it later when rendering and it worked fine . Thank you but i still don't understand why it changed

Comment: Think about updating this thread: http://forum.jogamp.org/Speeding-the-display-td4032405.html Let us know whether it just works as expected.

Comment: hi gouessej , no that's the main probleme and i still got nothing for the momement , in this example i was just trying to use glBufferSubData in order to figure out how it works and maybe that will give me a hint about the reason why the code i posted in that thread is not working . but i'm back on it right now and i'll update as soon as i got results . thank you :)

Comment: @user2545854, did you solve?